# Downloading image from url and assign it with a specified id from csv file

Tags: python, image, download, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a csv file with columns: image_id, image_url

I need to download all the images from the URL and save it as the corresponding image_id as the name. Is there a way to do so?

I'm aware you can do so with python from codes that i've seen online such as

```
import cStringIO # *much* faster than StringIO
import urllib
import Image

try:
    file = 
urllib.urlopen('http://freegee.sourceforge.net/FG_EN/src/teasers_en/t_gee-power_en.gif')
    im = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read()) # constructs a StringIO holding the image
    img = Image.open(im)
    img.save('/home/wenbert/uploaderx_files/test.gif')
except IOError, e:
    raise e
```

but how do you reference the url and the filename from the csv
even better if i can automate the process to uploading to a GCP bucket

Appreciate any help i can get. 
Cheers!

Comment: Can you post your csv file?

Comment: I did a mockup of my csv file. you can download it here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=93876903698031448894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Use the **[csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)** to parse through your CSV file.

**Ex:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import cStringIO # *much* faster than StringIO
import urllib
import Image

def downloadFile(imageID, url):
    try:
        file = urllib.urlopen(url)
        im = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read())  # constructs a StringIO holding the image
        img = Image.open(im)
        img.save('/home/wenbert/uploaderx_files/{0}.gif'.format(imageID))
    except IOError, e:
        raise e

with open('PATH_TO_.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:
        print row
        downloadFile(row[0], row[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

I have produced a python script below. I have only tested this in python 3.4.3 but should do the trick.

Hope this helps.

```
import urllib, csv, requests, os
from pathlib import Path


spreadsheetAddress = 'C:\\SOURCE\\CSV\\FILE.csv'
targetDirectory = 'C:\\TARGET\\IMAGE\\SAVE\\LOCATION\\'

def getSpreadsheetContents(spreadsheetAddress):
    with open(spreadsheetAddress) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        imageSet = {}
        for row in readCSV:
            if 'image_id' not in row:
                imageSet[row[0]] = row[1]
    return imageSet


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.path.exists(spreadsheetAddress) and os.path.exists(targetDirectory):
        imageDict = getSpreadsheetContents(spreadsheetAddress)
        for key, value in imageDict.items():
            if requests.get(value).status_code == 200:
                filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(value)
                address = str(targetDirectory + "\\" + key + file_extension)
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(value, address)
    else:
        raise Exception("File not found")
```

Comment: This also has validation in to check if file addresses and URLs exist.

Comment: This was easy to apply. Thanks :)